# Add dynamic textfield based on another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to Add dynamic textfield based on another ViewController via user input from another ViewController

Example:

BaseViewController -> User input (how many TextField to generate?) -> Send button
ViewController -> User input from BaseViewController = 5 then -> Generate 5 textfields on ViewController.

Hope this helps you, I really can't figure it out. tried searching for tutorials for adding dynamic textfields but unfortunately it doesn't fit on what I need.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a for loop as below;

```
int no_of_textfields = userInputTextField.text.intValue;
for (int i = 0; i < no_of_textfields; i++) {
    UITextField *a_textfield = [UITextField new];
    // initialize the text field as you want, place it appropriately
    [self.view addSubview:a_textfield];
}
```

Comment: However I need to add these textfields to another view Controller, not on the same one.

Comment: You can do 2 things. 1) Make the user input textfield a public property of the first view controller and access it from the second one. 2) Add an integer property named no_of_textfields to the second view controller. Set it in the first view controller when you're opening the second view controller.

Comment: You can use Tableview on 2nd ViewController with cell having textfield in it and generate number of rows based on user input from 1st controller.